# Cannot convert source type 'string' to target type 'uint' error in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am developing an win-forms application in VS 2010 to retrieve data from `Sql Server` or `MySQL`.

In this I am assigning connection sting by using below GUI.

[image: GUI Screenshot]

and adding or modifying MySQL connection string of destination by below function.

```
    private static void CreateDConnectionString(string server,string port, string dataBase, string userId, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            var connectionBuilder = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
            {

                Server = server,
                Port = port,
                Database = dataBase,
                UserID = userId,
                Password = password
            };
            //Open the app.config for modification
            var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            //Retreive connection string setting
            var connectionString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DConnection"];
            if (connectionString == null)
            {
                //Create connection string if it doesn't exist
                config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings
                {
                    Name = "DConnection",
                    ConnectionString = connectionBuilder.ConnectionString,
                    ProviderName = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
                });
            }
            else
            {
                //Only modify the connection string if it does exist
                connectionString.ConnectionString = connectionBuilder.ConnectionString;
            }
            //Save changes in the app.config
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"Need to work on configration");
            throw;
        }
    }
```

In this function on code

```
Port = port,
```

I am getting error that Cannot convert source type `string` to target type `uint`

Comment: Just a note, it's not `unit`, it's `uint`. It means _Unsigned Integer_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.Port` is of type `uint` (unsigned integer), and you're trying to assign an object of type `string`: these types are not compatible, there is no implicit conversion between them.

You should first verify whether the string can be converted to `uint` like so:

```
private static void CreateDConnectionString(string server,string port, string dataBase, string userId, string password)
{
    uint portNumber;
    if(! uint.TryParse(port, out portNumber))
    {
        //unsuccessful parse, report error to the user

        return;
    }

    //...
}
```

**Edit**: fixed bug in code

Answer (score 2):

Port doesn't accept a string value.

It takes an int

http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder~Port.html

So either pass it an integer, or use `Int32.Parse(port)`

Edit: Apparently contrary to the documentation, its a uInt

```
Uint32.Parse(port)
```

Comment: tried with int now it's showing 'Cannot convert source type 'int' to target type 'unit''

Comment: Uint is an unsigned integer (in that case use UInt32.Parse())

Answer (score 1):

```
Port = port,
```

You need to convert your string port to the datatype of Port

```
Port  = Convert.ToUInt32(port, 16);
```